# SQL Multiple Joins

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 4 tables (as shown in the picture), I want to select Invoice, Client for which invoice is issued, And all the items for which the invoice is issued.

I cannot figure out how? How should I apply joins, or should i use sub queries?

Please helpe me, I am really struck.

[image: Tables]

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Have you actually tried? Start with using JOINs, probably no need for subqueries.

Comment: Figure out the matching primary and foreign keys and you'll be able to write the join pretty easy.

Comment: you need `join`, go and do it, if you had problems write your query in the question

Comment: Never use subqueries as a first choice.

Comment: Such a query is almost natural language. You want to select invoces, clients and items where client and invoice share the same client id and where invoice and item have a matching row in invoiceItems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Select c.ClientID, i.Invoiceid, it.itemId 
from Clients c
Inner Join Invoice i ON i.ClientId = c.ClientId
Inner Join InvoiceItems ii on ii.InvoiceId = i.InvoiceId
Inner Join Items it on ii.ItemId = it.ItemI
Order by c.Clientid, i.Invoiceid, it.itemId
```

One can add additional columns as needed.

Answer (score 2):

Simple `INNER JOIN` should work

```
SELECT I.ItemID,
       C.ClientID,
       IV.InvoiceID
FROM   Items I
       INNER JOIN InvoiceItems II
               ON I.ItemID = II.ItemID
       INNER JOIN Invoice IV
               ON IV.InvoiceID = II.InvoiceID
       INNER JOIN Client C
               ON C.ClientID = IV.ClientID
```

Answer (score 1):

What's the problem? It's simple join

```
Select * From InvoiceItems ii
Join Items i on ii.ItemID = i.ItemID
Join Invoice inv on ii.InvoceID = inv.InvoiceID
Join Clients c on inv.ClientID = c.ClientID
```